# Django Channels: Could I know who is the sender of a message?

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-channels

I'm using Django channels 2.1.1

So, this is my logic, one Websocket instance is getting messages of the same type "alarm.data" from 2 differents groups. One group "alarms" and another groupr "alarms_specific_for_user_IDUSER"

Could I know where they come from whitout adding a "tag" in the text message?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No you will need to put it into the message from the `self.scope['user']` property from the Channel that created the message.